# Can I burn a small dvd iso to a cd in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, burning

I have an ISO image downloaded from MSDN (Expression Studio 4) that is listed as for a DVD.  The image is only 284MB.  Can I burn this to a CD instead, using the software built in to Windows 7, or will something in the file format tie it to a dvd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just double click the ISO file (*), it should open with `Windows Disk Image Burner`, this utility will allow you to burn the ISO file to external media.

[image]

(*) If you have installed any ISO handling utilities, right click and choose `Open With` then select `Windows Disk Image Burner`.

Personally though, I like use [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) (available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com)) for burning.

Anyway, whatever you use, if the actual ISO file is under 700MB, you should have no problem burning to a disk.

Lastly, if it is for the machine you are on, consider using a disk mounting program such as [Slysoft Virtual Clonedrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) - it both saves disks and is much faster!